# How do you make a Randomizer do an action, out of a lot more actions using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a randomizer that will pick an action out of 5. But here's the problem, when I run the script it doesn't pick an action out of the five. It just runs the action on line 3. Here's the script that I've done:

```
Randomize   
 a=Int((5 * Rnd()) + 1)   
 If a=5 then dim result
result = msgbox("Are you sure you want to install?", 4 , "Select yes or no")
 If a=4 then c="Yes"  
 If a=3 then c="No"   
 If a=2 then c="Maybe"   
 If a=1 then c="Ask Me Later"  
 b=inputbox("What Is Your Question?") 
 c=msgbox("" & c)
```

Those lines of code is suppose to be an oracle of sorts, with a secret.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

God, this is embarassing:
Actually I tested you code just now, aaaaand: it works fine for me. Sooo maybe you should specify your problem again?!

---

Answer with `Select Case`

```
 Randomize()
 a=Int((5 * Rnd()) + 1)

 Select Case a
    Case 1
       c= "Ask Me Later"
    Case 2
       c= "Maybe"
    Case 3
       c = "No"
    Case 4
       c = "Yes"
    Case 5
       dim result
       result = msgbox("Are you sure you want to install?", 4 , "Select yes or no")  
 End Select

 b = Inputbox("What Is Your Question?") 
 c = MsgBox("" & c)
```

Comment: When I run the script, it only runs the, "Are you sure you want to install?" and doesn't randomize.

Comment: Okay, first: In what order do you want the messageboxes to pop up? _Are you sure you want to install?_ -> _What is your question?_ -> _Answer_ or is _Are you sure..._ only supposed to pop up when c = 5? Maybe specify that exact path of events again in your question. It will be easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using a single line `If..Then` statement, which you cannot have multiple actions assigned to.  Try this:

```
Randomize   
 a=Int((5 * Rnd()) + 1)   
 If a=5 then 
     dim result
     result = msgbox("Are you sure you want to install?", 4 , "Select yes or no")
 End If
 If a=4 then c="Yes"  
 If a=3 then c="No"   
 If a=2 then c="Maybe"   
 If a=1 then c="Ask Me Later"  
 b=inputbox("What Is Your Question?") 
 c=msgbox("" & c)
```

It's worth noting (as in other answers and comments) that where you have multiple `If` statements, it's often better to use a `select case` statement like this (I've also renamed the variables for easier readability):

```
Randomize   
randomNum=Int((5 * Rnd()) + 1)   
Select Case(randomNum)
    Case 1 : randomResponse = "Ask Me Later"
    Case 2 : randomResponse = "Maybe"
    Case 3 : randomResponse = "No"
    Case 4 : randomResponse = "Yes"
    Case 5 : Dim result
             result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to install?", 4, "Select Yes or No") ' this option seems unwanted given your desired behaviour
End Select
userQuestion=InputBox("What Is Your Question?") 
' should probably do something with userQuestion 
' if it's empty you still return the random answer from above
' so only return the response where it's not
If Len(userQuestion)> 0 Then
    MsgBox(randomResponse) ' don't need to append an empty string or set it to anything
End If
```

Comment: Personally, I would use [`SELECT CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614(v=vs.84).aspx) instead of so many `IFs`

Comment: So would I. I also wouldn't have the whole `result` bit since it doesn't appear to be used anywhere, I would use variable names with some form of meaning rather than `a`, `b`, and `c`. But the purpose was simply to demonstrate/explain where the OP was going wrong in their coding, not rewrite it from scratch for them.

Comment: Since we all are trying to help each other, the more things you can correct the better it is for the community. :-)

Comment: I don't argue that point; but just replacing a series of `IF` statements doesn't actually explain to the OP where the error was.  I've demonstrated what the problem was and how to fix it.  I'll edit the answer and add a version using `select case` to demonstrate the better practice though.

Comment: I'll give this script a shot.

Comment: Is there a way to make the question run before Case 5 pops up? I've just tested it...